# Return selected function arguments

Tags: r, function

I have a function and want to return only the argument names of the function when called.

```
f<-function(a=NULL,b=NULL,c=NULL,a_unit=NULL,b_unit=NULL,c_unit=NULL){
return(formalArgs(f))
}
```

This returns all parameter names in the function How do I make it return only the names of the arguments that have been called?

```
function(a_unit="char1",b_unit="char2")
```

should return only the argument names "a_unit" and "b_unit".

I want to assign these names to another list that is inside the function

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, although I'm not 100% certain how robust it may be to odd corner cases:

```
f<-function(a = NULL,b = NULL,c = NULL,a_unit = NULL,b_unit = NULL,c_unit = NULL){
    names(match.call())[-1]
}
```

@Moody_Mudskipper helpfully suggested

```
rlang::call_args(match.call())
```

which may smooth out some of the stranger cases.

Comment: or `rlang::call_args(match.call())` but that's really the same, hiding the weirdness and covering the corner case where dots are used and they're all unnamed. And if it's expected not to return arguments that went into the dots : `match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)` might be used (and `...` element removed)

Answer (score 2):

```
f<-function(a=NULL,b=NULL,c=NULL,a_unit=NULL,b_unit=NULL,c_unit=NULL){
    formalArgs(f)[!sapply(mget(formalArgs(f)), is.null)]
}
f(a_unit="char1",b_unit="char2")
#[1] "a_unit" "b_unit"
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit, like what exactly `formalArgs` returns and how that interacts with `mget`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option

```
f <- function(...) names(rlang::enexprs(...))
f(a_unit = "char1", b_unit = "char2")
#[1] "a_unit" "b_unit"
```